# Remove space before day and month from DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I have a datetimepicker in a windows application and i want to remove the extra space before the single digit day and month.
[image]
Is there any way to remove this extra space before day 2 and month 1?

Comment: it preserves space even after applying the format "M/d/yyyy".

Comment: than you need to check you code again becase there might be some issue

Comment: So there is no way to remove that extra space ???

Comment: possible solution is customformat property as it not working for you i dont know another way to do it

Answer (score 1):

I think you can not change/remove the spaces before the date and month values because your `DateTimePicker` is set to the custom format `M/d/yyyy` which displays Month and Date in single digit only(by leaving one digit space before month and date if they are less than 10).

as an alternative you can add `Zero` before month and date (if they are less than 10).

Try This:

```
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can apply customer format to your DateTimePicker control

read this for more detail : [DateTimePicker.CustomFormat Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx)

Example

```
public void SetMyCustomFormat()
{
   // Set the Format type and the CustomFormat string.
   dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
   dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy - dddd";
}
```

Comment: I have tried this. In code behind date is coming without spaces, but is not reflecting actually.

Comment: Even when right format - dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "M/d/yyyy"; - is applied, it preserves space before month

Comment: yes it preserves space even after applying the format "M/d/yyyy".

Answer (score 0):

You can try using custom format. this.dateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "MM/d/yyyy";

Comment: No this doesn't solves the problem. It still preserves the extra space before single digit day and month.